# Delete blank line BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Can not understand
How to delete empty lines? 
.strip().replace("\n","") does not work

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen   
headers = {'accept': '*/*', 
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
base_url = 'https://book24.kz/product/kapitanskaya-dochka_14//'  
def BB_parse(base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
        for count, tag in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_='name')):
            ISBN1 = soup.find_all(class_='val')[count].text if tag.text == 'ISBN' else ''
            ISBN = ISBN1
            print(ISBN)
```

Print:

```
'empty line'
    978-5-17-115171-3
'empty line'
'empty line'
'empty line'
'empty line'
```

in case
i need to display all the characteristics separately

'ISBN'
'Возрастное ограничение'
'Издательство'
'Авторы'
'Серия'
'Переплет'
'Вес'
'Количество страниц'
'Ширина'
'Высота'
'Дата последнего тиража'

Page:

```
<div class="catalog-detail-properties">
                <div class="h4">Характеристики</div>


                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Возрастное ограничение</span>
                        <span class="val">12+</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">ISBN</span>
                        <span class="val" itemprop="isbn">978-5-17-115171-3</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Издательство</span>
                        <span class="val" itemprop="publisher"><a href="/publishers/izdatelstvo-ast/">АСТ</a></span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Авторы</span>
                        <span class="val" itemprop="author"><a href="/authors/pushkin-aleksandr-sergeevich/">Пушкин Александр Сергеевич</a></span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Серия</span>
                        <span class="val"><a href="/series/luchshaya-mirovaya-klassika/">Лучшая мировая классика</a></span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Переплет</span>
                        <span class="val" itemprop="bookFormat">Твердый</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Вес</span>
                        <span class="val">0.299</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Количество страниц</span>
                        <span class="val" itemprop="numberOfPages">384</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Ширина</span>
                        <span class="val">125</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Высота</span>
                        <span class="val">200</span>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="catalog-detail-property">
                        <span class="name">Дата последнего тиража</span>
                        <span class="val" itemprop="datePublished">05.04.2019</span>
                    </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: You can simply do `if ISBN: print(ISBN)`

Comment: Problem is that you assign default value '' to ISBN1

Comment: Not clear to your question.What you are trying to achieve here??would you like to get only ISBN value `978-5-17-115171-3` from this url?confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Empty strings are evaluated as `False` in the boolean context

```
>>> bool('')
False
```

So you can check it before, like this.

```
if ISBN.strip(): # strip incase of something like '   '
    print(ISBN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code with css selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
base_url = 'https://book24.kz/product/kapitanskaya-dochka_14/'
def BB_parse(base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
        print([item.text for item in soup.select('.name')])
        print([item.find_next('span').text for item in soup.select('.name')])


BB_parse(base_url, headers)
```

**Output**:

```
['Возрастное ограничение', 'ISBN', 'Издательство', 'Авторы', 'Серия', 'Переплет', 'Вес', 'Количество страниц', 'Ширина', 'Высота', 'Дата последнего тиража']
['12+', '978-5-17-115171-3', 'АСТ', 'Пушкин Александр Сергеевич', 'Лучшая мировая классика', 'Твердый', '0.299', '384', '125', '200', '05.04.2019']
```